# Как определить, что отображается в UIWebView?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Доброго времени суток.

У меня такой вопрос: в iOS-приложении есть UIWebView. Над ним расположен Text Field, пользователь вводит в него URL-адрес, и он загружается. Но если пользователь переходит по ссылке на другую страницу, то содержимое Text Field не меняется. И в этом нет ничего странного, потому что я не знаю, как это реализовать.

Фактически мне нужно определить, какой сайт в данный момент отображается в UIWebView. Подскажите, как это сделать? А то я в гугле не нашел ничего, в документации по UIWebView тоже. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

[Источник](http://mohrt.blogspot.de/2008/10/getting-url-from-uiwebview.html)

Comment: О, самое то, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Если мне память не изменяет, в делегате эту фичу убрали, сейчас люди так извращаются:

```
NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

Comment: NSLog выдал очень много всего, даже в этот комментарий не поместилось, как из этого получить только URL? Или может есть другой способ какой-то?

Comment: `- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` у делегата есть такой метод, может, это вам надо? и свойство `request` у WebView